# Maxima how to re-arrange terms?

Tags: maxima

This should be dead simple in Maxima: I have this equation `75.0*R+0.225*C=105`

How can I re-express this into R?

In other words, how do I get Maxima to  show me `R= (105-0.225*C)/75`?

Comment: Try `solve(e, R)` where `e` is your equation. Likewise try `solve(e, C)` to get a result for `C` in terms of `R`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@RobertDodier wrote in a comment that one uses `solve` to do this.

```
(%i1) 75.0*R+0.225*C = 105
(%o1) 75.0*R+0.225*C = 105
(%i2) solve(%,R)
rat: replaced 0.225 by 9/40 = 0.225
rat: replaced 75.0 by 75/1 = 75.0
(%o2) [R = -(3*C-1400)/1000]
(%i3) %[1]
(%o3) R = -(3*C-1400)/1000
(%o3) R = -(3*C-1400)/1000
(%i4) %,numer
(%o4) R = -0.001*(3*C-1400)
(%i5) %,expand
(%o5) R = 1.4-0.003*C
```

Comment: That's more like it! Thanks!